# facebook login using native activity not fbdialog/webview in my android app

Tags: android, facebook

I downloaded the facebook SDK and hackbook application. that is working fine. What i want is to **login through a custom android activity having userID and password EditText controls and a login button**. clicking on login button should perform fb login. i dont want webview to be used in my app or fbdialog.

appreciate your help

Comment: Is it good ? .... coz if the user types in password in edit text you can get his password and can misuse it....

Comment: but there are many app that work like that. likes of facebook app, social hub samsung mobiles and many more

Comment: Facebook is the actual app where u have account so they directly take user name and password, coz the verification is done by Facebook only. Your app is a 3rd party app, which requires authentication from Facebook and NOT from your app. So you need to authenticate yourself from Facebook and get the ACCESS TOKEN, only using this token you can communicate with facebook...

Comment: does that mean we can't do authentication without using a webview/fbdialog

Comment: Well if you are able to do that let me know as well....

Answer (score 2):

No, this is **highly** recommended against doing so and many users will likely never use your app because they are putting in their Facebook credentials into a dialog that they do not trust.  The whole point of using Facebook login in 3rd party apps like yours is to obtain an **access token**, which serves as a way for your app to communicate to Facebook *without* having your app access the user's Facebook credentials.

Our Android SDK provides native SSO if the user has the Facebook for Android app installed, and a webview popup if they don't.  Users can safely type their credentials into our webview because they can trust that they are providing their Facebook credentials to, well Facebook itself.

Do not create your own activity where the user has to put their Facebook credentials into your app.  It is bad practice and your users will not trust your app as a result.  Use the Facebook SDK for authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jesse. I have a device that is customised. Last time i tested an app on it by opening facebook mobile site in webview but it crashed. I am affraid if i reapeat same thing by letting user to signin through webview it may crash.